# How do I the change spinning pinwheel in 10.11 El Capitan to any GIF image?

Tags: macos

How do I change the spinning pinwheel in 10.11 El Capitan into any GIF image that I want?

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_pinwheel#/media/File:OS_X_10.11_Beta_Beach_Ball.jpg]

Comment: What do you want to change it to?

Comment: To some .gif image or list of png images, I want to know way how to do it.

Comment: @IronCraftMan and ChikabuZ I've edited your comments into the question, so it would be best to remove them.